# D3 svg paths overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

Wondering if anyone could provide any advice that I've encountered where paths seem to overlap eachother, thus not allowing other paths to be hovered over, or clicked upon.

I have modified the order in which they are placed on to the map, so that the 'covered' paths are ahead in the DOM, but I've still experienced strange results where the paths that were originally covering the smaller paths seem to be hoverable/clickable in an area much greater than over their own path.

An example that I think will help explain better that I have encountered live is here:

https://www.bromley.com/winter/explore/trail-map/

If you look at the right-most blue trail called 'Pushover', you will see what I mean. Hover over the trail and move your pointer away from it to the left and down, it will still be hoverable far beyond the extend of the path.

Not sure how to go about troubleshooting this kind of issue.

Comment: [`pointer-events: stroke;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) is your friend. If I add that property to `.TrailMap-view path` only the strokes themselves will be targets for pointer events.

Comment: @altocumulus post this as an answer

Comment: And yes, if you post this as an answer, I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which parts of an SVG path can become targets for pointer events, i.e. mouse clicks, is defined by the value of the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) attribute. Inspecting the code from the site you linked to one can easily see that for the paths the property is set to `all` by

```
.TrailMap-view .scene { pointer-events:all }
```

The definition for this value is as follows:

> **all**
>   The element can only be the target of a mouse event when the pointer is over the interior (i.e., fill) or the perimeter (i.e., stroke) of the element. The values of the [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill), [stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke) and [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/visibility) attribute do not affect event processing.

This means, that the interior of these paths will be a legitimate target for mouse events even if they are not visible to the eye. Since you only want the strokes of the paths to trigger the mouse events, all you need to do is set the `pointer-events` property to either:

- `stroke`

  > The element can only be the target of a mouse event when the pointer is over the perimeter (i.e., stroke) of the element. The values of the [stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke) and [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/visibility) attribute do not affect event processing.
- `visibleStroke`

  > The element can only be the target of a mouse event when the [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/visibility) attribute is set to visible and when the mouse cursor is over the perimeter (i.e., stroke) of the element. The value of the [stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke) attribute does not affect event processing.